# Pandas Dataframe groupby: apply several lambda functions at once

Tags: python, pandas

I group the following pandas dataframe by 'name' and then apply several lambda functions on 'value' to generate additional columns.
Is it possible to apply these lambda functions at once, to increase efficiency?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A','A', 'B','B','B','B', 'C','C','C'], 
                   'value': [1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3], })

df['Diff'] = df.groupby('name')['value'].transform(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0])
df['Count'] = df.groupby('name')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.count())
df['Index'] = df.groupby('name')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.index - x.index[0] + 1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  name  value  Diff  Count  Index
0    A      1     0      2      1
1    A      3     2      2      2
2    B      1     0      4      1
3    B      2     1      4      2
4    B      3     2      4      3
5    B      1     0      4      4
6    C      2     0      3      1
7    C      3     1      3      2
8    C      3     1      3      3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is possible use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with one function, but not sure if better performance:

```
def f(x):
    a = x - x.iloc[0]
    b = x.count()
    c = x.index - x.index[0] + 1
    return pd.DataFrame({'Diff':a, 'Count':b, 'Index':c})

df = df.join(df.groupby('name')['value'].apply(f))
print(df)

  name  value  Diff  Count  Index
0    A      1     0      2      1
1    A      3     2      2      2
2    B      1     0      4      1
3    B      2     1      4      2
4    B      3     2      4      3
5    B      1     0      4      4
6    C      2     0      3      1
7    C      3     1      3      2
8    C      3     1      3      3
```